# Stop browser scripts caching in GWT App

Tags: gwt, browser, caching

I have a GWT app deployed onto our client's machines. As an ongoing
development alongside, we have to release new improved versions of the
application fron time to time. Everytime we release a new version we
often run into the problem where the client's browser has cached the
old scripts scriptsand for a while it behaves strangly as the data it
is trying to work with is not quite compatible with it. What is the
best way to overcome this problem. Currently I have to tell the users
to clear their browser's cache for a new release but it would be nice
they don't have to do this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default, the bulk of your app should be cached by the browser until a new version of it is generated by your build process.

It might help to understand the GWT bootstrapping model to understand how this works.

The first script your client requests, `your-app-name.nocache.js`, is not cached, and it does nothing except check the browser's user agent and capabilities, and make a second request for the relevant app JS.

At this point, the script it requests should be cached by the browser if it's been requested before.  This is a `{indistinguisable-numbers-and-letters}.cache.html` file.

When you redeploy your app, the `nocache.js` file will be executed and ask for a different `cache.html` file from the server, which will not already be present in the cache, but which will get cached by the browser once it is downloaded.

Are you doing anything unusual with deferred binding, or with caching headers on your server?  This might potentially be causing your `nocache.js` file to get cached after all, which would make it request old `cache.html`s from the browser cache.

Comment: Jason, it looks like it is a side effect of your-app-name.nocache.js being cached in the browser. Shahid has to configure his server to cache only *.cache.js and to not cache *.nocache.js. 

Other than that everything you mentioned should fall in place automatically.

Comment: @jason-hall any ideas on how to inject some hash to the url of the scripts which are loaded via your-app-name.nocache.js? In my case the your-app-name.nocache.js is loaded correctly without caching, but the scripts which are loaded as a result of it, are still from cache. I would like to generate a hash at every build and add it to the url...

Answer (score 15):

Possible solution depends on the way you are hosting your application. If you are hosting directly from servlet container, then you can use servlet filter like the one described here:

http://seewah.blogspot.com/2009/02/gwt-tips-2-nocachejs-getting-cached-in.html

Here are appropriate filters from tadedon library:

http://code.google.com/p/tadedon/source/browse/tadedon-servlet/src/main/java/com/xemantic/tadedon/servlet/CacheDisablingFilter.java

http://code.google.com/p/tadedon/source/browse/tadedon-servlet/src/main/java/com/xemantic/tadedon/servlet/CacheForcingFilter.java

And here is guice ServletModule which enables them for the whole guice web application:

http://code.google.com/p/tadedon/source/browse/tadedon-gwt/src/main/java/com/xemantic/tadedon/gwt/http/GwtHttpCachingModule.java

If you are using some reverse proxy in front of tomcat it would be even simpler. In case of apache (e.g. mod_proxy, mod_jk), and assuming that all the application resources (html, graphics, java scripts, css, etc.) are put on apache, just set these options in apache configuration:

```
<Files *.nocache.*>
  ExpiresDefault "access"
</Files>

<Files *.cache.*>
  ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 year"
</Files>
```

It is described here:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html

in "Perfect Caching" section. Such deployment scenario assumes that only rpc requests should go through reverse proxy to tomcat. If for some reasons all the application context is proxied to tomcat you can still use apache's `LocationMatch` directive instead of `Files` directive.