# GWT failed to get the serialization policy

Tags: gwt, serialization

When I deploy newer version of my GWT application, I get sometimes this log error:

```
SEVERE: GwtRpcEventSrvc: WARNING: Failed to get the SerializationPolicy 'www.host.com:22041/MYAPP/'; a legacy, 1.3.3 compatible, serialization policy will be 
 a result.
```

- Question 1) Is it a problem of serialization policy files remaining
  in browser cache?
- Question 2) How to prevent such log message? I tried to add changing
  URL request param to nocache.js (`<script
  src="MyApp.nocache.js?v=123"...`) but it did not help.

Answer (score 7):

Try clearing your **browser** cache. It worked for me.. after searching a lot of a lot of ways to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

See:

- [how to clear cache in gwt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274053/how-to-clear-cache-in-gwt)
- [Stop browser scripts caching in GWT App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407649/stop-browser-scripts-caching-in-gwt-app)
- [GWT Caching Concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138767/gwt-caching-concept)

In summary: you need to set HTTP headers not to cache the .nocache.js files via your web server or a servlet filter